# How to scan an array of objects inside other objects

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Everybody, good afternoon, everybody,

I’m trying to access the attributes of a javascript object array via ajax, but I’m not succeeding, can anyone see where I’m going wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh8KV.jpg)

My ajax call is like this:

```
$("#cbx1").on("change", function() {

var checkbox = $("#cbx1").val();
console.log(checkbox);
if(checkbox == "TF") {
    var url = "/listar-perguntas?area-tematica=" + $(this).val() + "&montar-navegadores=true";
    console.log("bateu aqui 1"+url);
} else {
    var url = "/listar-perguntas?area-tematica=" + $(this).val();
    console.log("bateu aqui 2"+url);
} 

$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    data : "",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let text = "<input>" 
        for (let x in data) {
            text += "<label>" + data[x] + "</label>"
        }
        text += "</input>"
        document.getElementById("temaFederal").innerHTML = text;
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data.statusText);
    }
});
```

});

In my html it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeeTz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first search for the object in which your label is stored. That is on the 10th position in the list. If the element is gonna be always on the last position you can simply do data[data.length -1] and that will select the last object on your list on root level. Once you have selected the object then you’ll need to do data[data.length - 1]?.teamnavigator?.bucket and that will give you the list on which your labels are stored.
You can now iterate over this list.

Other wise you may search for the element first and then get your bucket list like this

```
const data = [
    { pergunta: 'lorem ipsum', guid: '1111'},
    { pergunta: 'lorem ipsum', guid: '1111'},
    { pergunta: 'lorem ipsum', guid: '1111'},
    { pergunta: 'lorem ipsum', guid: '1111'},
    { pergunta: 'lorem ipsum', guid: '1111'},
    { 
        areatematicanavigator: {},
        temanavigator: {
            bucket: [
                {
                    key: 'key',
                    label: 'label',
                },
                {
                    key: 'key',
                    label: 'label',
                }
            ]
        }
        
    }
]

const objectOfInterest = data.find(item => 'temanavigator' in item)

const buckets = objectOfInterest.temanavigator.bucket
for (let index in buckets) {
    console.log(buckets[index].label);
}
```

Edit: This is my first reply on stackoverflow. Pardon me for my silly mistakes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Many thanks my brother for his reply

Comment: You’re welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if that resolves your issue.